# R function with variable args depending on presence/absence of other args

Tags: r, variadic-functions

i've stumbled upon the varargs issue in R two or three times, but it seems that the problem i have is a little bit trickier than i expected. Here it is

i have a function, which does something with its variables, but i would like to introduce another variable, kind of a flag, that selects the way the function is working and which parameters are needed by the function itself: namely the number and type of inputs depends on a (flag) input.

Ok, an example is better:

```
example = function(x,flag=1,y){
    if (flag) return(x)
    else return(y)
}
```

and this is working fine. 
The point is that in this example you need to specify both x and y every time. Instead I would like a function taking **only x** if flag=1 and **only y** if flag=0. (In this stupid example they basically would be two distinct functions, but in my actual case i have other (common) arguments on i do some calculations that both 'parts' of the functions need).

I know that one may specify whatever value for the unused argument and the result wouldn't change, but i want a function which is immediately readable by the user, and it is cumbersome to need to specify an argument which won't be used by the function

thank you for any help

Comment: I don't understand your issue. "in this example you need to specify both x and y every time" is simply not correct. You can do `example(y = 2, flag = FALSE)`.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following.

```
example = function(x,flag=1,y){
  if (flag && !missing(x)) return(x)
  else if(!flag && !missing(y)) return(y)
}
```

This will check if the flag is 0 or non-zero plus it will check if an argument is missing. You may want to handle the case when neither of these is true cause this function will return NULL in that case.

Comment: yes, i know the use of missing() and this is indeed a solution..but i don't like the fact that just reading the argument list you are not able to tell which arguments are needed and which are not